# problema con arrays y condiciones, aparente fallo logico c++

Tags: c++

Tengo planteado el siguiente problema:

Un numero se dice trino si existe una diferencia de 3 unidades entre las cifras
contiguas que lo componen. Así, por ejemplo, 147 lo es, ya que 4-1 = 3 y 7-4 = 3.

También lo es 30, y por supuesto 96, 63 y 963. Sin embargo, 32, 98 o 145 no son números trinos.

Se pide escribir una función que determine cuando un numero es trino.

He resuelto el problema a partir de dos variables auxiliares que van restando la posición [i]-[i+1] de la mantisa numérica. El problema es que cuando la mantisa se trata de dos cifras no funciona, y no veo una alternativa a mi código. ¿Se os ocurre alguna idea para solucionar esto?

Espero que se entienda mi pregunta, muchas gracias por responder :D

Adjunto código por si sirve de algo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
typedef array <int,100>tnumero;

bool trino(tnumero &tnum, int lon_num);
void mostrar_datos(tnumero &tnum, int fin);
int ncifras(int num);

int main(){
    int num;
    tnumero tnum;

    cout << "introduzca una cifra ";
    cin >> num;

    int lnum=ncifras(num); //¿cuantas cifras tiene num?
    int inicio=lnum-1;
    int aux_num=num;
    for(int i=0;i<lnum;i++){ //rellenar array
        tnum[inicio-i]=aux_num%10;
        aux_num=aux_num/10;
    }

    cout << trino(tnum,lnum);
    //mostrar_datos(tnum,lnum);
}

int ncifras(int num){
    int ncif=0;
    while(num>0){
        num=num/10;
        ncif++;
    }
    return ncif;
}

void mostrar_datos(tnumero &tnum, int lon_num){
    for(int i=0;i<lon_num;i++){ 
        cout << i << " posicion= "<<tnum[i]<<endl;
    }
}

bool trino(tnumero &tnum, int lon_num){
    int resta_a, resta_b, condicion=0;

    /* if(lon_num==2){  // AQUI ESTA MI PROBLEMA.
    resta_a=abs(tnum[0]-tnum[1])==3;
    condicion= true
    }*/
    if(lon_num>3){
        for(int i=0; i<(lon_num-2);i++){

            resta_a=abs(tnum[i]-tnum[i+1]);
            resta_b=abs(tnum[i+1]-tnum[i+2]);

            if((resta_a==3) && (resta_b)==3){
                condicion++;
            }
        }
    }
    return condicion==(lon_num-2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu lógica es errónea:

```
bool trino(tnumero &tnum, int lon_num){
    int resta_a, resta_b, condicion=0;

    if(lon_num>3){
        for(int i=0; i<(lon_num-2);i++){

            resta_a=abs(tnum[i]-tnum[i+1]);
            resta_b=abs(tnum[i+1]-tnum[i+2]);

            if((resta_a==3) && (resta_b)==3){
                condicion++;
            }
        }
    }

    return condicion==(lon_num-2);
}
```

Parece que estás restando una cifra (`[i]`) de la siguiente (`[i+1]`) y esta de la posterior (`[i+2]`). Para empezar, los números de dos cifras no van a tener tres cifras que comprobar, y para acabar tu comprobación final da resultados erróneos para números de dos cifras:

```
condicion==(lon_num-2)
```

La longitud de un número de dos cifras es dos, si le restas dos es cero; si ninguna cifra está separada tres unidades entonces la condición será `0==0` que es verdadero, aunque el número no sea un trino.

Tu código es complicado de más e innecesariamente largo. Sólo necesitas una función, ir leyendo cifras y comprobar la diferencia entre las cifras leídas hasta quedarte sin cifras:

```
bool trino(int numero)
{
    if (abs(numero) <= 13)
        return false;
        
    int cifra = numero % 10;
    numero /= 10;

    while (numero)
    {
        int siguiente = numero % 10;
        if (abs(cifra - siguiente) != 3)
            return false;
        numero /= 10;
        cifra = siguiente;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDJasMwED1LXzFNKViHkJj25uVfFFl2B@yR0UKhId/uTmzFoeT4nt42MvN8NKOmYVnekcyYOgs1uhC91VMrZQpIA5CebJi1sRBiV0l5cW6E6JFcgRSB0mS9U/IqBfZQ6EsoMgV1A@WnkkJ4G5Mn6PUYbMWYpew02HsNTU6ADyjP/JjRqVmhFD/fOFp4ZErBPas74JDQUrQvCfuOreD4lCp4a2Bd9DLpf60Qj3G7l8kbz8m@6BMzTNynTBqpUNftKg5iqXEpQl3DgSnvuvRrNCTS@ebDXYEEbbvJn/rtX5lU1d7Fe27LUn7JPw)</kbd>.